# Plot curve using pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 2 curves with 5 data points:

```
a = np.array([['16x28', 0.023392, 0.006976],
              ['64x36', 0.029888, 0.039104],
              ['512x288', 0.033328, 2.198592],
              ['1024x576', 0.065632, 5.864992],
              ['3840x2160', 0.801120, 76.550461]])
```

when I plot it, I expect 2 curves but get straight lines instead:

```
plt.xticks([0,1,2,3, 4],a[:,0])
plt.plot(a[:,1])
plt.plot(a[:,2])
```

[image: plot curves]

How can I make pyplot plot curves like it should be?

**UPDATE:** I use Python 3.5.2 and matplotlib 2.1.1

Comment: What do you mean with curves? Are they nodes of polynoms? Please try to define better what you want to achieve - maybe an example image

Comment: If you look at the data, it is clear, that it won't be the straight lines.

Comment: This is the output of your code on my Python 3.6.2 and matplotlib 2.0.2 setup: https://snag.gy/ifVmPa.jpg , is this what you wanted?

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Works fine for python 2.7.13 and matplotlib 2.0.2, too.. can you post your versions?

Comment: Your values are all strings...

Comment: @O.Suleiman it is exactly what I expect. I use Python 3.5.2 and matplotlib 2.1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matplotlib < 2.1 does not allow the plotting of strings directly, however matplotlib 2.1 does. If you examine your data you will see that they are strings:

```
print (a[1,1], type(a[1,1]))
# 0.029888 <class 'numpy.str_'>
```

Therefore, you need to convert your data to floats. You can do this using [`numpy.ndarray.astype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.array([['16x28', 0.023392, 0.006976],
              ['64x36', 0.029888, 0.039104],
              ['512x288', 0.033328, 2.198592],
              ['1024x576', 0.065632, 5.864992],
              ['3840x2160', 0.801120, 76.550461]])


plt.xticks([0,1,2,3,4], a[:,0])
plt.plot(a[:,1].astype(float))
plt.plot(a[:,2].astype(float))
plt.show()
```

Giving:

[image]